# user.emailVerified doesn't change after clicking email verification link firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

After learning sending [email verification is possible in latest firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432106/1757321), although the docs are missing that, I wanted to test it for myself.

Using the snippet below:

```
  Auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
    if (firebaseUser) {
      console.log(firebaseUser);
      if (firebaseUser.emailVerified) {
        // console.log(firebaseUser.emailVerified); 
        toastr.success('Email verified');
      } else {
        toastr.info('Do verify email');
      }
    }
  })
```

The `console.log(firebaseUser.emailVerified)` returns false, always, although a send verification was initiated, email received, and clicked on.

Right after login with email, I check to see if user is verified, if not, email should be sent:

```
Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(function(firebaseUser) {
    if (!firebaseUser.emailVerified) {
      firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();
      console.log('Email verification sent');
    }
    $state.go('home');
  })
```

Under my `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-app-name/authentication/emails`, everything is by default, with a verify link as:

`Follow this link to verify your email address.
https://my-app-name.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>`

The email I use to sign up receives the verify email message, yet, clicking the link does nothing to change the `user.emailVerified` to true.

Are the steps outline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432106/1757321) all there is, or there's yet another step not found in the docs?

Comment: try running the `reload` method on the current user. 
`firebaseUser.reload()`
that should refresh the `emailVerified` var.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned by [Tope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/857115/tope) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900447/user-emailverified-doesnt-change-after-clicking-email-verification-link-firebas/42503983#comment72134229_37900447), you need to do a `firebaseUser.reload()` in order for the change to the firebaseUser's authentication status to be updated.

Comment: Yes, but when you will reload? How do you know that the user has visited the link in an email?

Comment: Maybe add a time expiration after 15 minutes?

Answer (score 9):

I just took the same steps:

```
auth.currentUser.emailVerified
```

> false

```
auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
```

1. wait for the email
2. click the link in the email
3. sign out
4. sign in again

And then

```
auth.currentUser.emailVerified
```

> true

Note step 3 and 4: I needed to sign in again, before the new value of `emailVerified` was visible in my app. Instead of signing out and back in again, you can also `reload` the user profile, which forces it to refresh the data from the server.

This answer also seems relevant, but I only spotted it after writing the above: [Firebase confirmation email not being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431128/firebase-confirmation-email-not-being-sent/37432106?noredirect=1#comment63252649_37432106)

Comment: On that note, then I don't need to do what is said here, as in applying the code? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#applyActionCode

Comment: The thread from here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/EGYwg2vjRq4/0KXEhucLAQAJ touches on the use of the applyActionCode, however, what I'm wondering if that is still needed or the verification now happens automatically

Answer (score 3):

In a very minimalistic way, this is what I ended up with:

```
angular.module('theApp')

.controller('emailVerifyController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'currentAuth', 'DatabaseRef',
  function($scope, $stateParams, currentAuth, DatabaseRef) {
    // where currentAuth and DatabaseRef is what they sound like
    $scope.doVerify = function() {
      firebase.auth()
        .applyActionCode($stateParams.oobCode)
        .then(function(data) {

          // change emailVerified for logged in User
          // you can update a DatabaseRef endpoint in here
          // whatever!

          toastr.success('Verification happened', 'Success!');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          $scope.error = error.message;
          toastr.error(error.message, error.reason, { timeOut: 0 });
        })
    };
  }
])
```

Then in template, something like this:

```
<a ng-click="doVerify()" class="button large">Verify my Account</a>
```

Although the `applyActionCode` is not yet wrapped for AngularFire, you could still drop down to vanilla Javascript of the SDK in your AngularJS stuff, besides, why not!

I share more details for Email Verification in Firebase: 
 https://blog.khophi.co/email-verification-firebase-3-0-sdk/

Answer (score 2):

We have just gone through the same issue and found the fix was to both reload user using `user.reload()` function and to also change the observer from `onAuthStateChanged` to `onIdTokenChanged`.

This is because you are updating the firebase token with the new `emailVerifed` property and `onIdTokenChanged` is listening for changes to the Id token and updates the user object with the correct values.

Code snippets:

```
export function* register_user(action) {
  try {
    //Call api which registers user and sets email verified to true
    let register_result = yield call(Register_API.create_registration, action.data)

    if (register_result && register_result.status >= 200 && register_result.status < 300) {
      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
      //Force user to reload so we can trigger the onIdTokenChanged listener
      return user.reload()
    }

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}


firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(function (user) {
      if (user && user.uid) {
        if (user.emailVerified) {
         //Stuff you want to do
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your code snippet or some sample code for others to refer.

Comment: worked with both  

await auth().currentUser.reload();
await auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)

Comment: current user reload didn't work for me but the get token refresh did. Might be api version though since we're kinda out of date unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it seems `currentUser.emailVerified` switches to `true`, but not always. Not sure why. It switches to `true` with Chrome in most cases, but not always. It does not with Firefox.

Applying the `reload()` method seemed to fix the issue.

I have the following in a saga, after loading the URL that contains the oobCode :

```
const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if(currentUser){
  currentUser.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We just need to reload the user's state after the user has clicked the user confirmation link. Especially if someone is using the firebase UI sign-in flow, one may have noticed that user Sign-up and Sign-in executes simultaneously. For such a case, the user needs to be reauthenticated by Sign-Out Sign-In, which is not a pleasant experience. However, Firebase provides an option to reload the user. Putting it inside the async-await function will make sure that the state is refreshed before executing the next commands.

```
async function confirmEmailVerified(){
    await auth.currentUser.reload();
    var isEmailVerified = auth.currentUser.emailVerified;
    if (isEmailVerified) {
        console.log("Email verified");

    }else{
        console.log("Email not verified, please verify or click on resend to get the verification email!");
    } 
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this and it still shows as false for email verified.

Comment: @carinlynchin If you are still looking for solution, please let me know, maybe I can look into your code and help you.

Comment: i ended up not using it... i was trying to use the action url... so I just took that out and the verify worked... it was for reactnative version

Comment: Two years later I found the same issue and I was able to solve it, I leave it  [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3597#issuecomment-1203375754) in case it can be useful to someone