# Email verification for Firebase Authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

How can you verify users that sign in with email and password with a verification email in firebase? How would the logic behind this work and how would it look in code?

Solution/Help: For those still looking for answers I found this Post   [StackOverFlow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035854/firebase-email-verification-doesnt-verify-account)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For Email verification**

You can send an address verification, email to a user with the `sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion:` method. As per [Firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) you can check from here.

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification { (error) in
  // ...
}
```