# auth().currentUser.reload() returns undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to check firebase emailVerified without logging out the user (Angular 6 web app), but auth().currentUser.reload() returns "undefined"

Tried:

```
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

auth().currentUser.reload().then((u) => {
  console.log(u);
});
```

Tried:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.reload().then((u) => {
  console.log(u);
});
```

These related issues **DO NOT HELP**.

[Update the email verification status without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53508364/update-the-email-verification-status-without-reloading-page)

[Firebase: Observe email verification status in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271839/firebase-observe-email-verification-status-in-real-time/50272808#50272808)

[Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload() doesn't refresh currentUser.isEmailVerified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126463/auth-auth-currentuser-reload-doesnt-refresh-currentuser-isemailverified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firebase core doesn't include the auth module. You need to add the auth module:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

If no user is currently authenticated, currentUser will be null and will not have a reload() function. Trying to call it would give you and error.

The reload() function returns a promise so you can use .then, but the promise doesn't return the currentUser object. To view the currentUser after the reload, just refer to the currentUser...

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
  firebase.auth().currentUser.reload().then(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(firebase.auth().currentUser));
  });
} else {
  console.log('No authenticated user');
}
```