# Firebase email verification behavior

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've got a question about how firebase email verification work.

**Case:**

1. My user signed in my site (using device A).
2. They create another account using other browser or device (device B), but they open email verification link with browser and device which he is already signed in (which is device A).

What happened to the already signed in user (in device A)? Is firebase signed them out or just verify new email, but still signed in with the current user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The email verification occurs out of band and would not affect any existing firebase states until it is reloaded**. If a user verifies their email, you have to call `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()` to update the `emailVerified` property. If you are using firebase rules with `emailVerified` field, you need to force a token refresh (`firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true)`) after verification. You can use the Firebase realtime database to set some flag on email verification and detect it in the existing session to force a user to reload. This would require you build your own custom email verification handler: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I've update my question to make it clear. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: I answered it. Email verification has no effect on existing sessions. Existing signed in users will remain signed in even if they are different users and regardless the device they are on.

Comment: Oh I got it, @bojeil. Sorry and thanks for the answer. How about same case, but instead verify email, it process password reset. Is password reset also has no effect on existing session?

Comment: Password reset will expire the token of any existing session for the same account. Reauthentication will be required.

Comment: So if it processed through <b>different</b> account, the user still authenticated?

Comment: Yeah if you reset the password on a different account, the other user would remain authenticated.

Comment: currentUser.reload() does not update the emailVerified property. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902082/679553

Comment: It should update it. Did you test it yourself? After you sign-in, the same endpoint as `reload()` is called to populate the user content.