# Firebase email verification WITHOUT creating an account in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have question regarding email verification in Firebase. Solution to my problem I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326951/firebase-email-verification-behavior). But when I convert code to react native. It is not working as expected.

**My function**

```
const onSignIn = () => {

auth()
  .signInAnonymously()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User signed in anonymously');

    auth()
      .onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        user.updateEmail('jasurkurbanov96@gmail.com');
        user.sendEmailVerification();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
      console.log('Enable anonymous in your firebase console.');
    }
    console.error(error);
  });

navigation.push('SignUpConfirm');

};
```

Basically what I want to achieve is. When user enters to app, I need to show only email input. Once user
enters email address, Firebase should send confirmation code to the email user provided.

Comment: what is the error ?. Both calls are async so if you not wait for updateEmail to finish, sendEmailVerification will throw an error.

Comment: 1) how did you know that it is async ?
2) My email is updating, but sendEmailVerification is not working.
3) I will see logs for errors than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the docs https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/user#updateEmail with the code below should works. if not print what error you got.

**Sign In Screen**

```
const onSignIn = () => {

auth()
  .signInAnonymously()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User signed in anonymously');
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
      console.log('Enable anonymous in your firebase console.');
    }
    console.error(error);
  });

navigation.push('SignUpConfirm');

};
```

**SignUpConfirm Screen**

```
useEffect(() => {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged((userIs) =>
      userIs
        .updateEmail('jasurkurbanov96@gmail.com')
        .then(() =>
          userIs
            .sendEmailVerification()
            .then(() => console.log('email verificiation sent')),
        )
        .catch((err) => console.log('This is', err)),
    );
  }, []);
```