# Firebase Realtime Database rules not working on the website

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have been searching in this forum that has helped me a lot to develop my entire project in firebase but I have not been able to find the answer to my question.

I have created a small voting app where users register and can only vote if they have verified their email. Every time a user registers, a verification email is sent with the `sendEmailVerification()` method.  Obviously I can (and I will) hide/show the UI based on `user.emailVerified` value (true or false) but for more security, I have configured the following rules:

```js
{
"rules": {
  //only users can write, noone can read
  ".read": false, 
  ".write": "auth.uid != null",
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
      //Inside /users, users can read/write in child /$uid only if the $uid of the user matches with the /$uid that is the branch name    for each user
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid", 
      ".validate": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "votos": {
        //only users that verified the email can read/write in this child object
        ".validate": "auth.token.email_verified === true",
        
        }
      }
    },

    "lists": {
    //only users that verified the email can read/write here
    //read is public because you dont need to be logged in to see the votes of the lists
    ".read": true,
    ".validate": "auth.token.email_verified == true",
    }
  }
}
```

I have done tests in the console simulator and everything seems to work correctly but when I go to the web it does not let me vote even though I have verified my email.

Basically I can only think of:

- I have not configured the rules correctly (but the console simulator gives me the results I expect)
- I have not configured the validations correctly
- It is not enough to send the verification email. Could it be that when the user verifies the mail, a token or something should be included in the url or in the user's data? I believe that `".validate": "auth.token.email_verified === true",` is done with the true or false value of `user.emailVerified` of the user, but I am not an expert in this...

The only thing I've seen similar is problems related to `user.emailVerified` not being updated after clicking the verification link and this made the value always false. But again, I have no idea.

If anyone can help me, I really appreciate it. This is my first question on the forum, sorry if I did something wrong.

Comment: Check if this can help you in email verification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900447/user-emailverified-doesnt-change-after-clicking-email-verification-link-firebas

Comment: Rules don't do anything on their own, but only become meaningful when exercised by code. Can you edit your question to show the minimal code with whith you get a problem, and in that code prove that it meets the conditions set out by your security rules (e.g. log the current user, and their `email_verified` value right before accessing the database).

Comment: I checked the link Tanay passed and yes, you need to do a firebaseUser.reload() in order for the change to the firebaseUser's authentication status to be updated. I tried signing out and sign in again and after this I was able to vote.