# Create user with email and password returns non null user with undefined values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following code; it successfully creates the user and returns a promise. According to the documentation, it returns a non-null user upon completion,  however, as i try to print out the email or send a verification email i get "undefined" and "sendVerificationEmail is not a function"

```js
function register(){
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    
    var promise = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // ...
        });
        
    if(promise != null){
      alert(promise.email);
      promise.sendEmailVerification();
      
    }  
    
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431128/firebase-confirmation-email-not-being-sent

This thread may help, I think you need to access the api before you use the sendemailverification api call.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how you access a promise. I'm not super familiar with the underlying Firebase code, but assuming they are using an A+ compliant promise solution then there should be a positive counterpart to the `.catch()` method. Its typically `.then()`.

So what that means is that you need to actually wait until the promise *resolves* before you can access what it is returning.

So instead of `promise.email` you would do something like this.

```
promise.then(function(rsp) {
  window.alert(rsp);
});
```

I also think it might make it easier if you were to ditch the whole promise variable. And do something like the following...

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(function(rsp) {
   // do something with rsp
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
```

Then it would be a bit more obviously what is going IMO.

I would recommend looking into promises a bit more here at [www.promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org/)