# Firebase how to verify an email address

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am using Ionic 2 and Firebase to Authenticate my users.

I want to make use of Firebase to **Verify a users Email**. Much the same way as resetting a password works here:

```
resetPassword(email: string, fireAuth: firebase.auth.Auth): any {
    return fireAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
}
```

This emails a link to a user, which allows them to rest their password.

Once a user registers:

```
fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((newUser) => {
    this.userProfile.child(newUser.uid).set({ email: email });
});
```

The new user has the following as expected:

```
emailVerified:false
```

I would like to call a Firebase function to email a verification link to the user, once they are verified, I can then allow them to login.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Here is some info https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification

Comment: This answer is also helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/37432106/782358