# Why Aren't Firebase Verification Emails Sending?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the Firebase verification emails to send. I am using Xamarin to create my mobile app with the [Xamarin.Firebase.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/firebase-auth) module. One of the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431128/firebase-confirmation-email-not-being-sent) mentions having to upgrade the SDK version, but I am using the latest available.

I thought it could potentially be an issue that I have a custom domain set up in Firebase for the sent emails, so I reverted back to the default and it still doesn't work.

Yes, I have checked my spam folder. :)

Any other suggestions?

Here is my current test code snippet:

```
FirebaseAuth oAuth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(oApp);

oAuth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtEmail.Text, txtPasswordConfirm.Text);

FirebaseUser oUser = oAuth.CurrentUser;

oUser.SendEmailVerification();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431128/firebase-confirmation-email-not-being-sent

Comment: I linked to that question in mine. The only relevant part seemed to be the version comments, but like stated above I am using the latest.

Comment: I do not have my C# code in front of me, but you have to do the send email *after* the auth request gives you a valid user. There are examples in that linked SO.