# How to send a verification email during registration? Firebase, React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a registration form, the user puts his info then I submit it to a firestore collection. I want to send a verification email with the same button, how can I do that?

here's my signup button.

```
 onSignUp() {
    if (
      this.state.email != '' &&
      this.state.password != '' &&
      this.state.name != '' &&
      this.state.phonenumber != '' &&
      this.state.lastname != ''
    ) {
      const { name, lastname, phonenumber, email, password} = this.state;
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
          firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('Patients')
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .set({
              name,
              lastname,
              phonenumber,
              email,
   
            });
          console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert('Sorry it seems you entered wrong email or/and password');
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      alert('Please, make sure you filled all the fields with correct info!');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send an email verification message call `user.sendEmailVerification()` after the account was created or signed in. So:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((result) => {
    result.user.sendEmailVerification();
    ...
```

Also see the RNFirebase documentation for that [method](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/user#sendEmailVerification).

Comment: I don't use RNFirebase, my project is made on expo blank, can i still use the same method?

Comment: @CliAd Yes with firebase user reference you can still call `user.sendEmailVerification()` check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432106/7561290

Answer (score 0):

There are too many modules which can be used.
I use ***nodemailer***.

**Official website**

https://nodemailer.com/about/

**yt video**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF9g1825mwk