# Firebase: sending user the email templates?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and I'm trying to send the default templates given in firebase. i want to send user the verification mail and check whether he has verified or not. But the problem is I didn't found any solution to my problem. I tried searching this on Firebase Documentation but didn't found that.

Lastly, I got this: [Firebase confirmation email not being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431128/firebase-confirmation-email-not-being-sent), but I wasn't able to use it also.

Can anyone help me? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

I'm developing for android app.

Comment: Email verification is not available in the Android SDK yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418518/email-verification-using-firebase-3-0-on-android

Comment: thank you man @FrankvanPuffelen