# Android: Firebase email verification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there any way to check **email** is **verified** or **not** before the **login**. I am sending verification links through Firebase email authentication its work successfully. But I tried to check is Email verified or not.

```
final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
                    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please verify your email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Firebase Authentication: Verify email before sign up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708624/firebase-authentication-verify-email-before-sign-up)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the user needs to be signed in.  There is no other way to get a User object so that you can call the `isEmailVerified` method on it.

Comment: Thank you but I have one more question how can I check user clicked or not in sending an email verification link