# How can I add a user in my authentication tab after verification done from email?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

What should I do to add a user in authentication tab after email is verified?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but if I understand exactly what are you searching, you can find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41780828/9631312 or listen to `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()` and when value changed update your auth tab or sign in with email link as described in the answer linked above. Anyway Firebase Documentation offers you anything you need, check out  https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides/