# How to get a specific given in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Example: I have a database that has name, email, but I want to know if this name matches a value that I put in an `editText`
Help me Thanks so much!!

Comment: Check the answers for your queries, in stack overflow before posting a question. This can help you save downvotes

Comment: This might help you: https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all initiate the database instance

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

get the reference of your DB where you want to perform the operation

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(NAME_OF_DATABASE);
```

then use this to get all the user with the name equal to the editText text

```
Query query = profileDbRef
            .orderByChild("name")
            .equalTo(edittext.getText().toString());
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot1.getKey() + "  " + dataSnapshot1.getValue(Profile.class)
                        .toString());
               }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Man, thank you very much I used this code and it worked in my project, however I wanted your help if possible in the following situation:
I ordered some data from my database but I wanted it to be in the reverse order, that is, from the largest to the smallest.
The biggest result: 100
The lowest result: 0
Would you help me or anybody?

Comment: There is no way to reverse the data by using firebase query you have to do it manually.. or it you are using it for a recyclerView data source it can be done by 
LinearLayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()); mManager.setReverseLayout(true);

Comment: Thank you so much man! But how do this in ListView ?

Comment: i got solve my problem! Your help was extremely important, thanks so much again!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Firebase, but I found this. I was able to find it pretty easily, so usually just search here once before posting.

You can have a look at this question.

[Swift & Firebase | Checking if a user exists with a username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442114/swift-firebase-checking-if-a-user-exists-with-a-username)

The question there was to do something similar using Swift. Might give you a good start.
As for getting the value of the EditText, it is as simple as this.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editext1);
String result = editText.getText().toString();
```