# Filtering Firebase object based on nested array

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I have a Firebase list of of images with a set of tags in my Angular2 app. I'm looking for a way to return all images with "Tag1". Is this possible using the `sort_by` function?

```
let arrayOfElements = 
    [
        {
           "name": "a",
           "subElements": 
           [
             {0: "Tag1"},
             {1: "Tag2"}
           ]
        },
        {
           "name": "a",
           "subElements": 
           [
             {0: "Tag1"},
             {1: "Tag3"}
           ]
        }
    ];
```

Comment: Please have a look at this this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844795/how-to-get-a-specific-given-in-firebase/40845176#40845176

Comment: just replace .orderByChild("name")
            .equalTo(edittext.getText().toString()); to  orderByChild("0").equalTo("Tag1")

Comment: Thanks Tabish! However, the "Tag1" could also have id: 2 for instance. Is it possbile to do this search without knowing the key of the dictionary I'm searching?

Comment: for that you have to separate that Tag1, Tag1, Tag3 in a separate table and only place there ids as keys in the subElement

Comment: I see. Using the javascript filter method seems to work as well but I wonder if this method should be avoided 

arrayOfElements.map(res => 
    res.filter(r => r. subElements.indexOf("Tag1") > -1))
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result))

Comment: You'll need to create a custom index that maps from each to to the elements matching that tag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value, which a.o. explains why the array in your structure is problematic (hint: it's a set, not an array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you need to sit and think about this, why? The reason is that you are front a tipical problem in firebase.... Answer this questions:

- **The** `arrayOfElements` **can be infinite?**
- **The** `arrayOfElements` **size can be less of 100 (for example)?**

Why you need to answered this questions? Supose that you have an **array of 10.000 items (or infinite items)** if you use `orderByChild("0").equalTo("Tag1")` the firebase database needs to reading all items to find the items have "Tag1", then your app/web needs **more time** and **data** to get result of this query, then here we need to start talk about **normalize firebase database** and it's time to create indexes, you can see my yesterday [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40887512/3996257) that I explain it.

If your answer in second question is **YES** then you can use this command to get values `orderByChild("0").equalTo("Tag1")` because the data consumed and time wasted is too low front other cases... You can solve this adding `indexOn()` on firebase database rules. Analize your database and decide the best option.

---

**Update**

About your comment... If you doesn't have an id or don't need firebase unique id the best form to do this, for me is this one:

```
arrayOfElements{
    tag1:"true",
    tag2:"true"
}
```

And just get the keys as value.

Let me know if I have helped you and good programming!

Comment: Thanks for that. In my case it would be <10 elements. However, the "Tag1" could be in any of the keys (0,1... n).

As posted above the manual filtering works, but might not be advisable?
subElements:

arrayOfElements.map(res => res.filter(r => r. subElements.indexOf("Tag1") > -1)) .subscribe(result => console.log(result))

Comment: My answer is updated, read it and tell me what do you think! ;)